# Finding the parent id of an product

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, sales, reports

I have a requirement to create a cross sales report(Which combination of the product is most purchased by a customer with it order count), But i want to avoid those orders contains parents and child,Suppose if an order contains P1 ,P2 and P3 products(P2 is the parent of P1) then i want to show the combination like P2 and P3(excluded the child),likewise i have to show the combination of products (excluding parent and child and showing parents only with other products).

So for this i have created a table where i'm updating the order , product details and parent details.But facing an issue to identify the correct parent of product(same child is having multiple parents),So how can i tackle this situation and find the exact and correct parent for each products.

i'm using the table catalog_product_relation for identifying the parent ,child relation(but in this for same child have multiple parents).

Any suggestions/recommendations will be of great help.

Need SQl code for this.
Version Magento 1.9, Will be updating to magento 2 soon.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want a SQL statement that gets all purchased items and returns the product id, name, and a count of how many times purchased, excluding parent products.

```sql
SELECT 
    order_item.product_id,
    sum(order_item.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered,
    (
        SELECT 
            name 
        FROM 
            el_sales_order_item 
        WHERE 
            el_sales_order_item.product_id = order_item.product_id 
        LIMIT 1
    ) as name
FROM
    el_sales_order_item as order_item
WHERE
    order_item.product_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            parent_id
        FROM 
            el_catalog_product_relation
    )
GROUP BY 
    order_item.product_id
ORDER BY 
    qty DESC;
```

Comment: It's not like that, I want the combination of products which is sold together along with their order count and excluding the childs if the parent item is present in the same order.For example an order contain 3 products p1,p2,p3 and p3 is the parent of P1.So i want the combination product to be displayed as p2,p3 and all the orders contains the combination p2,p3

Comment: hope you understand the scenario now.Can you please help me with it.?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
     $childProductIds = array('1','5'); //suppose child product ids given statically (or) dynamically we can do by using for loop
     $childProductId = implode(',',$childProductIds);
     $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($childProductId);
```

//For Magento2

```
          $productId = 4; //child product id
          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
         if(isset($product[0])){
          //parent product id..
         echo $product[0];
        }
```

Comment: For the Magento 2 example, instead of using Object Manager. You should either inject that `Configurable` class within either the block or into a viewmodel.

Comment: @Sam Do you have the SQL code for this,Means how to get the parent id

Comment: @Nadh Same question, It is for SQL reporting.Do you have the SQL code for it?

Comment: Is the product your looking up also in a bundle / grouped product? `catalog_product_relation` contains bundle/group/config relations. Whereas `catalog_product_super_link` contains only config relation. | Otherwise can you edit your question and include, what your statement looks like so far. So we know where you are getting your data. @SandeepSalim

Comment: @Sam Yes,The products includes bundles/grouped products also. I was referring the table catalog_product_relation  to find the parent -child relationship, since a child has multiple parents i was unable to find the exact parent. I haven't used the catalog_product_super_link table, i will check and update you.

Comment: @Sam Can you please help/Suggest any solution for this? This problem is making my report system faulty for a long time,If you can guide on this, i'll be much grateful.